# How to list environmental variables on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, environment-variables

How can list environmental variables on Windwos Server 2008 R2 using command promt?

Comment: On powershell I could use: get-childitem env:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it has always been done since DOS times:

```
set
```